# Making Symfony 2 project cookieless

Tags: symfony, cookieless

I am trying to make Symfony 2 project cookieless as I have no requirement for cookies on my site.

Comment: The answer below appears to solve your question. Would you accept it? To do so, click the tick mark to the left of it so that it turns green. This is how we mark a question as solved on Stack Overflow, and it credits the answerer with some points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable `stateless` firewall to disable cookies.

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            stateless:  true
```

Further documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#stateless-authentication).